# Making sense of an encoded JSON string

Tags: disassembly, file-format, hex

I extracted a game file, which is in JSON format, it's a bit too long, so I'll omit parts of it:

```
{name: "\xEE\xB5k~u\u03D7\x80\xF8\xE0\xE2\xC5\xCA\xEE\u04CF\x90\xBE\xD8Cs\xFE\xA5Ec\u007F\u0006\x85\xA2\xB2\xD87",
      f03: 2,
      f04: 300,
      f05: "\xE5\u007Fe\u0001\xF7\xFCC\x87\xF0xK\xF7",
      desc: "l8\x88\xF6\xCE\u0012\xC8-8g>{\xE6&\xAB\u03E4f\x8C\u0012\xDD/\x81\x91\xF7\u007F\xD2\u0019\u000E\x87\xF7\xF07Ek\xFC\xCEtU\u0002\x9F@eJ\xB0\xFA\x93\xA8>5\x9BK\xAF\xE0\u001D\xA1\u0006\xE8\u001D.r\xF5\u041F\u05CB1\xF5J\u000F\"\xC6\u001B4\xB7\u0000\x97o\xA4>\u00158q\xE4\x9B\xE2z51N\fe{\xECV\u0011\xAE']|#X'\b\xCE\u0005\xEEg\xC3\uFE9Be\u0018\xC0\xDE\u0006>;\u0002\xFB\u0002;j\xC4{\xE9\u0013P\xE8a\xC9C\x8B\xE65\x87\u063Ac(o\xB1\xD9\xF4\xAF\xC0_D\u001B\xE7\u0013n\u0306\x81\xD9W\xA8\xC9:\x96\x93\xC7\u0006\u0014\xA8\x8E\xC0\x96*q\u000E<\xC1\xA1\u0005\xC6\xD9\xE5\u0007(t;\x92\x8B^\x91c\xFB=l"}
```

I'm having trouble how to make sense of `name`, `f05` and `desc` fields, no idea how to decode them. It seems like a mix of hex and Unicode.

The game is able to convert them into readable format, so there must be some way to decode them.

For reference, the `name` string translates to `'[A Duty to Honor]' Kirito`, and `f05` is for `serif`.

If anyone can tell me on how to decode this, it'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are *encoded character strings* in the form of *byte streams*.

But before encoded, they are highly likely somehow obfuscated or  **encrypted** – and this is the main problem.

The *decoding* itself is not a such problem – you need to know how they are encoded, or try different encoders one after other (in spite there are [many tens of them](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) as `big5`, `cp273`, `iso-8859-5`, `gb18030-2000` – but some of them are only for specific natural language / languages).

If you know the encoder (or at least the natural language of your game to limit the set of possible encoders), you may decode it, e.g. in Python, as I will show you:

Preparation:
I will encode a string (in Python) to receive a byte stream similar to yours:

```
>>> "Ľαaβ4γ•a∞".encode("utf-8")
b'\xc4\xbd\xce\xb1a\xce\xb24\xce\xb3\xe2\x80\xa2a\xe2\x88\x9e'
```

Note the notation - the letter `b` (for byte sequence) immediately followed by the encoded string in apostrophes (quotes are good, too).

**Proper decoding:**

```
>>> b'\xc4\xbd\xce\xb1a\xce\xb24\xce\xb3\xe2\x80\xa2a\xe2\x88\x9e'.decode("utf-8")
'Ľαaβ4γ•a∞'
```

Particularly, for the value `"\xE5\u007Fe\u0001\xF7\xFCC\x87\xF0xK\xF7"` of your key `f05` (don't forget to put `b` at the beginning):

```
>>> b"\xE5\u007Fe\u0001\xF7\xFCC\x87\xF0xK\xF7".decode ("utf-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

So it is definitely NOT encoded as `utf-8`.

You may try other decoders from [this table](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), e.g. `unicode_escape`:

```
>>> b"\xE5\u007Fe\u0001\xF7\xFCC\x87\xF0xK\xF7".decode ("unicode_escape")
'å\x7fe\x01÷üC\x87ðxK÷'
```

It is better, but – as I already wrote – you will never obtain directly the string `"serif"`, because it is in the encrypted form. You have in addition to **decrypt** the result of decoding, but it is impossible without knowledge of the encryption schema and a decryption key.

Comment: The game uses a library called libcocos2dcpp.so which is in C++ as far as I know. So basically I'll need the "key" which helps to decrypt the text right?

Comment: You need a key **and** to know *how* it is encrypted (encryption algorithm / schema), if it is properly encrypted (i.e. by known established algorithms / schemas). But it may be obfuscated in another way (i.e. amateurishly). No multibyte decoding (utf-8, utf-16, utf-16-le, ...) gives something similar to your string `"serif"`, so it is evidently somehow changed (encrypted, obfuscated) before transforming to the byte stream (encoded). Or it may be first encoded, then changed.